# Issue while trying to deploy model on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I am deploying a python ML model using Flask on Heroku. Here is GitHub link with all my procfiles and requirements.txt files https://github.com/shrey10926/ineuron-project/tree/master.

I am first creating my project repository on GitHub and then using Heroku to deploy my model via GitHub option. Below is the traceback:-

```
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
           main()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 263, in main
           json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py", line 133, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
           return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-mmu23e6l/overlay/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 166, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
           self.run_setup()
         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-mmu23e6l/overlay/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 258, in run_setup
           super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-mmu23e6l/overlay/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 150, in run_setup
           exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
         File "setup.py", line 583, in <module>
           setup_package()
         File "setup.py", line 579, in setup_package
           setup(**metadata)
         File "/tmp/pip-build-env-mmu23e6l/overlay/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 137, in setup
           config = configuration()
         File "setup.py", line 477, in configuration
           raise NotFoundError(msg)
       numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No lapack/blas resources found.
       ----------------------------------------
   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python 
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py 
prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmphdo6r3ju Check the logs for full command output.
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks fine. I checked your Github repository then I realized that your main branch is empty while your master branch is ok. Check your Heroku configuration is what branch is used for. (main/master ?). It might be based on the main branch.

`https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/your-app-name/deploy/github`

Comment: I selected master branch only while deploying as all the files are in master branch.